# Converting Hex To Ascii Memory Access

Tags: c

So I have a memory block that is fill with hex values, and I want to read in those hex values as Ascii. Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

```
char* charstring = malloc(sizeof(uint16_t));
uint8_t test = 0x65;
sprintf(charstring, "%x ", test);
fprintf(Output, "%s", charstring);
free(charstring);
```

This just gives me a ton of "65", not the "e" I was expecting.
I know it's a simple question, but I've literally clicked every link on the front page of google and can't figure out my problem!

Comment: `char* charstring = malloc(sizeof(uint16_t));` <-- What on earth is this? Where is your string terminator?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I saw on a few of the google pages that people were passing pointers to sprintf to hold the converted hex value, so I made my own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get `65` because you are using `%x` as the format specifier, change it to `%c` for the character value.

Note that you don't have enough space for `charstring` for the null terminator. Fix it.

Comment: GAHH, i read on one if the sites that it was x. Thank you, that fixed everything!